Calculation of Ages Regarding Marriage in Dharmasutras, Dharmashastras and Nitishastras
I am curious whether the ages of marriage in those texts which expound the sacred law are calculated with the origin being conception or being after one has finished his vedic studies?

For girls, the basic rule is before menarche. However, authorities differ. Vasistha dharmasutra goes to the extreme by advocating literally infant marriage. For boys, it is after samavartana, a samskara which marked their return back from gurukula & release from the vows of brahmacarya. The return depended on the ability of the individual to grasp the teaching & devotion to study.

So the age is calculated at 0 from when they return to a gurukulam? Which means the man is much older than he actually is.

@Haridasa Never heard about such a rule. However, child marriage isn't restricted to a sexually active man marrying a pre-pubescent girl, marrying such a girl to a pre-pubescent boy is also considered as child-marriage, & after the decline of the gurukula system & regular recital of the Veda, upanayana & samavartana are performed on the same day. So both adult-child & child-child marriages were happening in the past.

@অনু I know the ages of marriage and I see nothing wrong in them after looking into other details, but I am just making sure I am reading the ages properly.

Either the man is older than 20 when he marries or the age stated.

@অনু ehh I only heard of the former
